# Regarding filtering in Excel (hiding rows)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a question regarding Excel:

I have a worksheet with a lot of information, but I need to see only the unique rows. If there are duplicates, I need to hide all of them or to delete them, for example:

```
       Column A            Column B
Row 1  05.645.084/0001-34  353,16
Row 2  05.645.084/0001-34  353,16
Row 3  05.645.084/0001-34  42,20
```

In this case I want to hide or delete the two duplicate rows (in this case Rows 1 and 2) leaving ONLY the unique rows (in this case: Row 3).

Is this possible? I have tried using advanced filtering and conditional formatting, but with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in Excel and count results](https://superuser.com/questions/1205009/remove-duplicate-rows-in-excel-and-count-results)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, that looked liked a dupe at first reading, but that one is about deduplication and this one wants to remove all records that are duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a solution that uses a Helper Column. You can then use the Helper Column to filter the data and decide to Hide or Delete the duplicates.

In this example the sample data is in cells A1:B15.
Use Column C as a Helper Column. Put the following formula in C1 and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula. Just drag it down till the intended rows.

```
=IF(SUM(IF(CONCATENATE(A1,B1)=CONCATENATE($A$1:$A$15,$B$1:$B$15),1,0))>1,"Duplicate","Unique")
```

This will reflect Duplicate or Unique as the case be. Now just filter your data using this Helper Column.

[image]

Just note that in the second CONCATENATE the row reference should match the actual rows with data for this method to be effective. You should not pre-fill  the blank rows with this formula. The results after last row shall be erroneous in that case. So in case after Deleting rows, you wish to apply the formula again, you may have to adjust the cell reference if more and more rows are getting added at the bottom. Otherwise use A:A, B:B in second concatenate but that would slow down the sheet.